# Router redirects mega.nz to gateway address

Tags: networking, router

I first noticed this problem when attempting to do a system upgrade (Linux Mint) and I couldn't upgrade the MegaSync client. Upon looking at the refused connection error output, I more or less immediately thought "that's my router!". Here is some sample output of `ping mega.nz`:

```
PING mega.nz (192.168.4.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.4.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=8.50 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.4.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.55 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.4.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.70 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.4.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.73 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.4.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.75 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.4.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.32 ms
```

And here is the output of `netstat -rn`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

...which confirmed my suspicion. If I reset the modem (Technicolor TC-4400AM) and Eero Pro, the problem goes away, but then returns after several minutes. To be specific I've both pulled the plug and waited for a bit and also done the same along with the paperclip reset on the modem. I've also made sure it wasn't a Linux Mint problem by doing everything up to and including a full reboot and trying to open mega.nz on my phone—same thing. Oddly enough MegaSync still works. I can also open the website by directing traffic through my SOCKS proxy (which is hosted on a VPS rather than here). Still, I don't like having to reset everything whenever I want to upgrade the client and don't want to just hack the apt source file to use the IP. These sorts of things really nag at me. The problem is specific to mega.nz; doesn't even apply to mega.io. I've never seen anything like this. Do I need to call my ISP or can it be fixed here?

Comment: Start by checking  DNS.  Switch to other servers and see if that helps.

Comment: Setting my phone's DNS server to dns.google was effective. Nothing on Linux Mint I've tried works, even after using the following two help pages: https://learnubuntu.com/change-dns-server/ and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-dns-nameservers and doing two reboots. I'm using 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and the diagnostic info comes out like it should, yet mega.nz still points to my gateway address.

Comment: I guess I can at least use my phone as a hotspot if push comes to shove

Comment: That is odd and should be investigated further.  You have nothing local that mediates your traffic?  DNS server, firewall (e.g. pfsense)?  Advertising blocker?  Clarify what *"the diagnostic info comes out like it should"* means.  Also test by changing the DNS servers on your modem/router, and see if that resolves it.

Comment: What does `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` give you?

Comment: @BlindSpots The diagnostic commands used were `resolvectl status` and `dig google.com | grep SERVER`

Comment: `nmcli` [etc.] indicates Google's DNS servers

Comment: I don't know about anything intermediate here other than my SOCKS proxy and I know when that is or isn't being used. I'd probably have to call my ISP regarding altering modem or router settings.

Comment: normally you can access admin settings, logs, etc. in your modem via the gateway address (192.168.4.1) and shouldn't need to involve your ISP.  Pwd is often written on the modem. What are the DNS servers/IP addresses used by your ISP? or what is your ISP?  Also can you confirm you are connect via ETH or is it WIFI via the mesh AP?

Comment: I got a "see no evil" monkey picture along with "Your device is not allowed to access this site". I use Blue Ridge which is a small ISP in northeastern Pennsylvania and I'm not sure how to figure out what they use. Also I am using WiFi in all instances. Funny thing is `resolvectl status` says that both `Global` and `Link 3 (wlp3s0)` say I am using Google's two DNS servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whitelist mega.nz on the Eero app. Open app > Discover > eero Secure > Block and Allow Sites at bottom

I had same issue and thought it was my pi-hole blocking it. Found it is the Eero Secure feature provided by my ISP.